# Calculating the integral $\int { \frac{2-x}{x^2-x+1} dx }$

Tags: integration

Using what method(s) do I calculate this integral? I tried but I have no idea what to use.

$$\int { \frac{2-x}{x^2-x+1} dx }$$

Answer (score 6):

**Hint:** Complete the square in the denominator: $$x^2 - x+1 = \left(x-\frac12\right)^2+\frac34$$

Now recall the following standard integrals: $$\int \dfrac1{x^2+1} \, \mathrm dx = \arctan x \qquad \int \dfrac {2x}{x^2+1} \,\mathrm dx = \log(x^2+1)$$

Can you combine these?

Answer (score 0):

Use the change of variables $\sqrt3z=2x-1$ and the primitives
$$
\int\frac{\mathrm dz}{1+z^2}=\arctan(z)+C,\qquad\int\frac{z\ \mathrm dz}{1+z^2}=\tfrac12\log(1+z^2)+C.
$$

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

$$\frac{2-x}{x^2-x+1}=-\frac{1}{2}\frac{2x-1}{x^2-x+1}+\frac{3}{2}\frac{1}{\left(x-\frac{1}{2}\right)^2+\frac{3}{4}}=$$

$$=-\frac{1}{2}\frac{(x^2-1)'}{x^2-x+1}+\frac{3}{2}\frac{\left(\frac{x-\frac{1}{2}}{\frac{3}{4}}\right)'}{1+\left(\frac{x-\frac{1}{2}}{\frac{3}{4}}\right)^2}$$

and now we just remember that for any differentiable function $\,f\,$ :

$$\int\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}dx=\log|f(x)|+C\;,\;\;\;\int\frac{f'(x)}{1+f(x)^2}dx=\arctan f(x)+C$$